# Flex mx:Legend paints outside it's container

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a chart with a legend

```
<s:VGroup  width="100%" height="100%">

        <mx:LineChart width="100%" height="100%" id="lineChart" showDataTips="true" dataTipFunction="columnChartDataTipFunction">
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis id="v1" title="Position" labelFunction="labelFuncY"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis
                    categoryField="kh_formatted_date" />
            </mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>                
                <mx:AxisRenderer id="vax" axis="{v1}" placement="top"/>
            </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
        </mx:LineChart>

        <s:BorderContainer width="100%" borderColor="#ff0000" borderWeight="4">

        <mx:Legend verticalGap="0" dataProvider="{lineChart}" clipContent="true" maxWidth="100"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:VGroup>
```

I have this result but I was expecting scrollbars, also maxWidth seems to be ignored.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this structure instead

```
    <s:BorderContainer width="100" borderColor="#ff0000" borderWeight="4">

        <s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
            <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                <mx:Legend verticalGap="0" dataProvider="{myChart}" clipContent="true"/>
            </s:Group>
        </s:Scroller>

    </s:BorderContainer>
```

to control the width of the legend you can use the width property of the BorderContainer

[image]

Comment: Hi,thx for the response, I do not need the border ,it was just for debugging, I will try your solution ,did I miss-understand the documentation of the Legend class and clipContent or it is a bug in Legend ?

Comment: I have always the same problem. I think it's a strange approach of spark components... Another point is, that Charts and Legends are still MX and they can't be integrated into spark containers straight forwards.